# Closing 4 functions with different parameters in to array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, function, dry

I could like to simplify my current code and close all four functions in array with passing equivalent parameters in to them .

```
function firstFunction() {
  if (sound) {
    var audio = document.getElementById("sound1"); 
    audio.play(); 
  }
  sound = true;
  $('#topleft').addClass('litTopLeft');
}

function secondFunction() {
  if (sound) {
    var audio = document.getElementById("sound2");
    audio.play();  
  }
  sound = true;
  $('#topright').addClass('litTopRight');

}

function thirdFunction() {
  if (sound) {
    var audio = document.getElementById("sound3");
    audio.play();  
  }
  sound = true;
  $('#bottomleft').addClass('litBottomLeft');

}

function fourthFunction() {
  if (sound) {
    var audio = document.getElementById("sound4");
    audio.play();  
  };
  sound = true;
  $('#bottomright').addClass('litBottomRight');

}
```

All functions have similar parameters that need to be passed by like :

```
 if (sound)
 sound = true;
 audio.play();
```

Rest of the parameters need to be equivalent to each function like:

```
var audio = document.getElementById("sound1");
$('#topleft').addClass('litTopLeft');
```

Comment: Not really clear what you're asking. You're aware that functions can have parameters, right?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I am.

Comment: What does this have to do with arrays?

Comment: @Barmar I thought array of functions will be best way to simply it.

Comment: How would that simplify it? You'll still have to duplicate all that code in each array element.

Answer (score 1):

Make all the values that vary between the functions parameters.

```
function playFunction(soundid, targetid, classname) {
  if (sound) {
    var audio = document.getElementById(soundid); 
    audio.play(); 
  }
  sound = true;
  $('#' + targetid).addClass(classname);
}
```

Then you call it like:

```
playFunction('sound1', 'topleft', 'litTopLeft');
```

You can remove one of the parameters if the target ID is always the same as the class with `lit` prefix removed.

```
function playFunction(soundid, classname) {
  if (sound) {
    var audio = document.getElementById(soundid); 
    audio.play(); 
  }
  sound = true;
  var targetid = classname.replace('lit', '').toLowerCase();
  $('#' + targetid).addClass(classname);
}
```

Then it's just

```
playFunction('sound1', 'litTopLeft');
```

Comment: Need one more parameter. The CSS class names are different too. Alternatively, it seems that the class name can be derived from the element name.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Actually, it's easier to go the other way, because of the camelcase in the class names.